# Issue running terminal commands through jupyter notebook

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I am currently running a [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/artkulak/workout-movement-counting/blob/master/test_code/LabelingScript.ipynb) from a github repo. One chunk goes like this:

```
for file in os.listdir('data/'):
    path = 'data/' + file

    os.system(f"python OpticalFlowGen.py --type {target} --file {path}")
```

The variables target and path were defined and no errors were raised.

When the OpticalFlowGen.py file is run on the terminal with `python OpticalFlowGen.py ---type 'Train' -- file 'data/video.mp4'`, a popup appears and closes after the video file is processed by openCV and .jpg files will be saved in the system. However, when this command is run on the jupyter notebook, nothing pops up and no files are saved. You can access this .py file from the same repository [here](https://github.com/artkulak/workout-movement-counting/blob/master/test_code/OpticalFlowGen.py).

Currently I have to run manually on the terminal file by file so save all the image output before I can run the notebook without error. However, it will become an issue when I have too many video files, not using the for loop will be too cumbersome. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In a Jupyter Notebook you don't have to use `os.system`, instead try to use `!`:

```py
for file in os.listdir('data/'):
    path = 'data/' + file

    # Use
    # ! - for terminal commands
    # {} - for a variable in the terminal command
    !python OpticalFlowGen.py --type {target} --file {path}
```